# Проблема с отступами html в Sublime Text 3

Tags: html, sublime-text, sublime-text-3

Редактируется html файлик.

Необходимо ввести такой код:

```
<div class="lala">
    <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Затруднение возникает на месте ввода тега `<p>`.

Сценарий:

1 шаг

```
<div class="lala">
```

2 шаг

```
<div class="lala">

</div>
```

3 шаг. Устанавливаем курсор с отступом (1 tab)

```
<div class="lala">
    |
</div>
```

4 шаг. Начинаем вводить и получается так:

```
<div class="lala">
<p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Куда то пропадает отступ когда вводишь текст.
Если его поставить повторно - то все сохраняется.
Но каждый раз дважды проставлять отступ очень утомительно.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы [**Emmet**](http://emmet.io/) по незнанию не пользуетесь, или на то есть какие-то иные причины? [**Меньше**](http://i.imgur.com/mjvBIiM.gif) ведь писать намного, и отступы не нужно исправлять. Спасибо.

Comment: У меня и [**не воспроизводится**](http://i.imgur.com/pIgz2ht.gif) Ваша проблема, дополнительные данные нужны. Но когда есть Emmet, полагаю, лучше не мучиться с ней. Спасибо.

Comment: По незнанию. Попробую его. Но в данном случае мне кажется еще что то можно сделать.

Comment: Skywave, [**в этой книге**](https://docs.zoho.com/file/nqgo4e3473558e032489e9dc3bceb3db16723), начиная со страницы 146, порекомендовал бы почитать про Emmet. Рассказывается о малоизвестных полезных возможностях.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лично у меня [**не воспроизводится**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5Sl3.gif) проблема ув-мого топикстартера: табуляция не пропадает. Нужны дополнительные сведения, только, на мой взгляд, это будет лишней работой как вопрошающему так и отвечающему, когда есть плагин [**Emmet**](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime).

Как вводится код в вопросе:

[image: Emmet не используется]

Насчитал 27 нажатий клавиш или их сочетаний.

Как набрать точно такой же код, используя Emmet:

[image: Emmet используется]

**12** нажатий клавиш либо их сочетаний против **27** — имеем более чем двукратный выигрыш во времени. Проблемы с отступом у меня также нет.

Материалов по Emmet в сети предостаточно, я бы порекомендовал почитать со страницы 146 книгу [**Sublime Text Power User**](https://docs.zoho.com/file/nqgo4e3473558e032489e9dc3bceb3db16723), где рассказывается о малоизвестных возможностях плагина.

Comment: Когда поставил emmet - проблема тоже исчезла